# OSGi 'await for listeners to subscribe'

Tags: spring, osgi

Let say I have kinda EventGenerator service in bundle A and Processors (listeners) in bundles B and C.
A knows nothing about B and C, where Processors make subscriptions for EventGenerator events on initialization.
There could be created more listeners in other bundles D, E etc.

In spring application I would do subscription while constructing Processor, passing EventGenerator as a constructor argument. I would have B and C logically dependent from A. On @PostConstruct I would have working system, ready to process events.

How could I initialize A, B and C as an OSGi application? I'm facing problem when EventGenerator starts to work and Processors miss events, because they are not yet initialized and subscribe for them.

Comment: If it is ok for you to configure EventGenerator via ConfigAdmin to wait for the specified Processors before sending the first event, I can show an example.

Comment: I think this is wrong for EventGenerator to know about it's listeners from architectural point of view. There could be added another bundle listener at any time. EventGenerator bundle should not be changed.

Comment: I meant a configurable component. This means that only configuration (via configadmin) has to be changed and not the EventGenerator bundle itself. In practice: When you want to have a new Processor, you drop the bundle into the OSGi container that contains the Processor, and than you open the webconsole and add the new processor to the EventGenerator on the configuration screen (or you do the configuration update programmatically if you write some deployment code)

Comment: You propose something like controller that should know about both EventGenerator and listeners and it should manage to do subscriptions and start EventGenerator on finish by itself. This will definitely work, but this architecture is rigid too. What I'm looking for is kind of @PostConstruct callback, not only Spring beans constructed in current bundle, but in all bundles of OSGi app. I would do all needed subscriptions on beans/services construction and start processing events afterProerptiesSet(). This will require only logical dependencies of listeners to EventGenerator.

Comment: "but in all bundles of OSGi app": You cannot not know how many bundles will be in the OSGi app. You cannot know if a bundle is replaced at runtime. If you use Spring, all knowledge is within one framework and the framework can only be re-deployed as one unit. If you use OSGi, your application is modular, and the modules have their own lifecycles. You cannot have a functionality like @PostConstruct in OSGi as there is no such state that everything is ready and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible in OSGi. The reason is that you cannot know at the time of deploying the bundle of EventGenerator, what bundle deployment events will happen and in which order.

In Spring everything is deployed at the same time therefore it can be analyzed, which beans implement the Processor interface.

There are a couple of workarounds, you must choose the one that is the best for you.

**LogService**

You can find the *Log Service* chapter in the OSGi specification. *LogListener* implementations can be registered as OSGi service. The *LogService* implementation picks up every *LogListener* service and sends every *LogEvents* for them.

The issue here is that a *LogListener* might be registered after that a *LogEvent* is already occured.

A solution here is to tell how many records should be memorized by *LogService* and if a *LogListener* is registered, send the last *X* events first. As much as I remember, the default setting of *Equinox LogService* is that it remembers the last 100 *LogEvents*.

**BundleTracker-like events**

The speciality of *BundleTracker* events are that the number of *active* events are limited. After an *event* is not relevant anymore, it is deleted. In practice:

- Until a *Bundle* is in the container, the last event of the bundle is stored and processed by every newly opened *BundleTracker*
- When a *Bundle* is marked for deletion, its last event is removed

In case you have events like this, you can implement the same approach. It is not easy to implement it. There is an library I implemented and makes the job easier. You need to implement some interfaces and define your types via Generics and you will have the necessary event management functionality: https://github.com/everit-org/eventdispatcher

**Wait for all Processors before starting EventGenerator**

In case non of the previous solutions work for you, you must tell somehow the *EventGenerator* component not to register its OSGi service until all *Processors* are picked up.

In my opinion, the best way if you make this configurable via *ConfigAdmin*. By doing that, you will be able to re-configure your *EventGenerator* component via the *CommandLine Console* or *WebConsole* without restarting your system.

I implemented a Component Model to have this functionality. Your component would look like the following:

```
import org.everit.osgi.ecm.annotation.Component;
import org.everit.osgi.ecm.annotation.Service;
import org.everit.osgi.ecm.annotation.ServiceRef;
import org.everit.osgi.ecm.extender.ECMExtenderConstants

import aQute.bnd.annotation.headers.ProvideCapability;

@Component
@Service
@ProvideCapability(ns = ECMExtenderConstants.CAPABILITY_NS_COMPONENT,
    value = ECMExtenderConstants.CAPABILITY_ATTR_CLASS + "=${@class}")
public class EventGenerator {

  private Processor[] processors;

  @ServiceRef
  public void setProcessors(Processor[] processors) {
    this.processors = processors;
  }
}
```

You can specify the necessary *Processor* OSGi services with an array of *OSGi filters* at the *processors.target* attribute of the component. The Component will start and it will be registered as a service after all processors are available.

To make the sameple above work, you must drop the following dependency (with their transitive dependencies, less than 200k) into your OSGi container:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.everit.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.everit.osgi.ecm.extender.ri</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There is a *WebConsole* plugin as well that shows the state of your component (why it is unsatisfied or failed):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.everit.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.everit.osgi.ecm.component.webconsole</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```